# MS SQL Design for Single Table Historical Data

Tags: sql, database-design

I know there are other posts about historical record keeping and many talk about auditing features and other features in SQL and whether to use a single table or a secondary or audit table.  This is most about how to use the single table method.

Building a client documentation application that will have historical data and not allow deletes.  The records will not have all that many revisions but over time there will be up to ten thousand active records and some small multiple of that for the historical records.

Fortunately, since this application is pretty small there shouldn't be much of a performance concern with almost any approach so ease on the development staff is important.

We've decided that keeping everything in a single table is probably the best approach for this application.  That said it is single table per needed table anyway.  For example, we have a table called Client and one called ClientInfo so each table will hold the historical data for their respective table.  Hopefully that makes sense.

What we need to do now is determine the way of tracking which record changed and which is active vs historical without making SQL statements a pure nightmare throughout this application.

Since all data is based on a Client, one proposal was to generate a custom ClientNum (which we are going to have anyway) and then use this for relations to all other tables instead of joining on the ID.  With this approach it would just be a matter of querying tables on ClientNum and getting the most recent InsertDate stamp on.  Course it might also be leading to each table having to have their own custom Num field like ClientNum in the Client table and ClientInfoNum in the ClientInfo table.

Or is it better to have a flag on whether the record is active or not?

Is this going to gain much over just using the identity ID of Client for the same purpose?

Is there a more appropriate way to use the single table historical data storage system?

EDIT

Here is an example of the ClientNum proposal.  They are both showing that the ClientName changed from ABC Company to ABCD Company.  How could you tell that these two records in the first example have anything to do with each other?

```
ID    ClientName      InactiveDate
----------------------------------
1   | ABC Company   |  09202014
2   | ABCD Company  |  NULL
```

Now in the example since we have generated a ClientNum and it is the same on both the original record and the new record it's easy to see that they are both for the same client and that one is the current data and one is the old.

```
ID    ClientNum    ClientName     InactiveDate
----------------------------------------------
1   | 8761348    | ABC Company   |  09202014
2   | 8761348    | ABCD Company  |  NULL
```

But I'd have to have a ClientNum type column, though it would be named relevant to the table name, in each table that needed historical data, which is all of them.  For the ClientInfo table there would need to be a ClientInfoNum generated so that I could make sure all historical records are associated with one another.

This is the part I don't know if I'm approaching correctly or if there is a better way to do this altogether.

Comment: Your description is wandering and doesn't make a lot of sense, you have a lot of assumptions and knowledge about your domain that we don't have so your comments about clients and what not mean nothing to us.

Comment: Your answer below is along the lines of what I was thinking so at least you could understand the general idea of what I'm thinking.  I can give as much detail as necessary that will help you help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple process.  You just have a field called "End Date" or "Inactive Date" or similar.  All active records have this field null.  When you create a new "version" of a record, you insert a new one, and set Inactive date on the previous record.   This simultaneously marks it as "inactive" and gives you a historical ordering of when it was made inactive.

This means you need only query on records where InactiveDate = null to find the current records.

Comment: This makes sense except how do you know that one version of the record is associated with another?  I made edits to the original question to give an example of just simply adding an InactiveDate vs. having the InactiveDate as well as generating the ClientNum that I was talking about.  See if this makes sense or if I'm missing a different way of doing this.

Comment: @Zookie - Yes, you have to have a field that ties them together.  This could be a field as you propose, or it could be a join table for a many to many, or you could just generate a unique number that doesn't change that isn't tied to the record ID.